# How to style a "list item > link" in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like:

```
$("#ofertas_cercanas").append("<ul data-role='listview' id='profile_list_close' style='max-height: 145px; overflow: auto;'>");
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.ofertas.length; i++) {
                        $("#profile_list_close")
                                .append("<li class='ui-nodisc-icon' data-icon='forward_arrow_merca'><a style='margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 15px; border-style: none; max-height: 50px; font-size: 0.8em; background-color: white !important;' href='#job_loaded_from_JSON_with_coordinates_to_user_profile_"
                                                + i + "'>"
                                                + "<div id='procesos_title'>" + data.ofertas[j].titulo + "</div>"
                                                + "</br>"
                                                + data.ofertas[i].empresa
                                                + "</br>"
                                                + data.ofertas[i].localidad
                                                + ", "
                                                + data.ofertas[i].provincia
                                                + "</a></li>");
                    }
...
```

And I was wondering how was the CSS selector to point the div which id is procesos_title.

Tried with

```
#user_profile .ui-content, #profile_list_close > li > a#procesos_title{
   color: red !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `<a>` element with an id of `procesos_title` in your markup. There is, however, a `<div>` element with that id.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle depicting your problem?

Comment: You have duplicate IDs in the appended HTML which is invalid. e.g. `id='procesos_title'` Use classes instead of IDs

Comment: inside the <a> I create a div with that id

Comment: You *cannot* have duplicate IDs on a page. Start by fixing that and come back with new HTML.

Comment: where is the duplicated?

Comment: Inside your loop... unless `data.ofertas.length` is always 1 you are adding the same id over and over. Best to view the DOM of the generated page (F12 Chrome DOM inspector?) and see what is being injected into your page.

Comment: I see it clear now yes!, been obfuscated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are stored in a browser fast lookup dictionary with one element per ID. For this reason (and the HTML spec) you cannot have duplicate IDs when you add dynamic elements.

Instead use a class for your `procesos_title` like this:

```
$("#ofertas_cercanas").append("<ul data-role='listview' id='profile_list_close' style='max-height: 145px; overflow: auto;'>");
for (var i = 0; i < data.ofertas.length; i++) {
    $("#profile_list_close")
        .append("<li class='ui-nodisc-icon' data-icon='forward_arrow_merca'><a style='margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 15px; border-style: none; max-height: 50px; font-size: 0.8em; background-color: white !important;' href='#job_loaded_from_JSON_with_coordinates_to_user_profile_" + i + "'>" + 
         "<div class='procesos_title'>" + data.ofertas[j].titulo + "</div>" + "</br>" + data.ofertas[i].empresa + "</br>" + 
         data.ofertas[i].localidad + ", " + data.ofertas[i].provincia + "</a></li>");
}
```

and reference in CSS via the class with:

```
#user_profile .ui-content, #profile_list_close > li > a.procesos_title{
   color: red !important;
}
```